# ¿Cómo documentar una API con Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

Estoy trabajando con Laravel, no tengo mucha experiencia y primera vez que me toca crear API y documentarla, para realizar la API no instale ningún paquete que se especialice en eso, lo hize todo asi manual por asi decirlo, pero si instale `Laravel Sanctum` para el `bearer token`.

Voy probando las rutas con POSTMAN y sin token no me deja visualizar los datos, por lo que me funciona bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema va que me pidieron documentar la API y no se como se hace, trate de guiarme con este video [Documentación de API's REST con Postman](https://youtu.be/RG-9JZ9gHwE) pero con los pasos que sale hay no logro obtener datos de la API, me fije en dejar el TOKEN ingresado en la colección y nada.

La API va a ser consumida solo para visualizar reportes al día con Power BI.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo a continuación el codigo:

**Rutas**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::get('/reports/unmanaged','Api\ReportController@getTicketUnmanaged');
    Route::get('/reports/managed','Api\ReportController@getTicketManagement');
    Route::get('/reports/quotes','Api\ReportController@getTicketsQuotes');
    Route::get('/reports/reserved','Api\ReportController@getTicketReserved');
    Route::get('/reports/validated','Api\ReportController@getTicketValidated');
    Route::get('/reports/close','Api\ReportController@getTicketClosed');
});
```

**Controlador**

```
public function getTicketUnmanaged(){
    $unmanaged = Ticket::ticketWithLeadForStatus(1)->has('solicitudes')->whereHas('source')->whereHas('contact')->get();
    return ReportResource::collection($unmanaged);
}
```

**Resource**

```
class ReportResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        //return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'project' => \App\Project::find($this->contact->project_id)->name,
            'model' => $this->model,
            'source' => $this->source->name,
            'score' => $this->contact->score,
            'validated' => $this->solicitudes->validated_form,
            //'type_contact' => $this->comments->first()->type->name,
            'seller' => $this->solicitudes->user->getFullName(),
            'status'=> $this->solicitudes->status->name,
            'change_status' => $this->solicitudes->updated_at,
            'created_ticket' => $this->created_at
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, ya se que es un poco pasado de tiempo, andaba buscando lo mismo y encontre este recurso puede servirle a otra persona.

Se podria usar según el recurso con https://swagger.io/

Swagger es un conjunto de herramientas de código abierto creadas en torno a la especificación de OpenAPI que nos pueden ayudar a diseñar, crear, documentar y consumir APIs REST de una manera sencilla.

El paquete para integrar Swagger que vamos a usar es darkaonline/l5-swagger que depende de otro llamado zircote/swagger-php con el cual que tendrás a la mano todos los tipos de anotaciones disponibles y además ejemplos.

https://styde.net/como-documentar-una-api-en-laravel-usando-swagger/

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/272028)

Comment: gracias, es mi primer respuesta no lo había pensado así.